# There is no any answer box for this post

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I would like to add an answer to this question but there is no any answer box for this question.

What is the reason?

[Nonequivalent definitions in Mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286732/nonequivalent-definitions-in-mathematics)

Comment: As you can see in [the revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/286732/revisions) and [in the timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/286732/timeline), the linked question is [protected](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/protected-questions/info).
Only users with reputation at least 10 can answer such questions - but I don't assume this is a problem in your case.
When I scroll to the bottom of the page, I can click on [answer this question button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JN4H.png) and after that, the answer box appears. (I am on a desktop - I did not check from a mobile device.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you. yes I am from a mobile. I try with desktop now

Comment: Somewhat related posts on [meta.se]: [Under what conditions is the answer box replaced with an "Answer this question" button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307768) and [Add a message when posting to old questions with more than N answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84870). (Buy I do not se anything about difference between a desktop and a mobile there.)

Comment: Is it possible that the problem actually is that if you have the [association bonus](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/association-bonus/info), then you actually need 110 reputation points to answer? It seems that you have asked about such problem previously: [There is no an answer button for certain Wiki question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3413). Other related posts on this meta: [Why I am not allowed to answer protected questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5152) and [Trouble understanding criterion to answer protected question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1120).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I have  again the same problem via desktop. I do not find an answer box  or answer this question button. I would appreciate if you help me

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Yes I see I forgot my meta question you linked too. any way I would appreciate if you help me to remove this problem(if it is possible for you)

Comment: I don't really know any other way how to resolve this than earning enough reputation points to get above the threshold. (Possibly some user [with sufficient reputation](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/protect-questions) could unprotect the question. But I assume they were reasons for protecting the question - so maybe it is better if it remains protected.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Ok, I see, Thank you

Comment: So, it seems this is a reason not to bounty yourself down below $110$.