# Why I am not allowed to answer protected questions?

Tags: bug, bounty, association-bonus, protected-questions

I'm a new user of MathOverflow. In the privileges section, it says that I can now answer protected question.
[image]

But in reality, when I visited [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/49403/178111) protected question, it says:
[image]
I'm not counting the association bonus, as I have already given all my association bonus points as bounty to a question. Is this a bug?

Comment: This seems to be a similar case here: [Trouble understanding criterion to answer protected question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1120). As far as I can tell, if some reputation was given away, it is more complicated. You can check the post on [meta.se]: [Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to answer protected questions because I gave away earned rep in bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231498) (and maybe also [other related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/231498).)

Comment: See also the post [Allow people to answer protected questions if they have earned at least some amount of combined SE rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129214/allow-people-to-answer-protected-questions-if-they-have-earned-at-least-some-amo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the [bounty you offered](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/403395/revisions) adds $-100$ to what counts as "reputation earned on this site" for the purpose of answering protected questions. At least, that is my understanding based on the explanation given here:

- [Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to answer protected questions because I gave away earned rep in bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231498) (Meta Stack Exchange; notice that it is tagged [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design)) - you might also check some of [the linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/231498).
- [Trouble understanding criterion to answer protected question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1120) (Meta MathOverflow - a detailed explanation is given in quid's answer)

Basically, so far you have (on MO):

- Started with 1 reputation point.
- Got the association bonus +100.
- Earned 10 reputation points from one upvote.
- Used 100 reputation points on a bounty.

That gives your current reputation, which is 11. But the association bonus does not count when checking whether a user can answer protected questions. So you have to add -100 and you're on -89. (In other words, you have to compare your current reputation with 110 reputation points, which is 10+100, i.e. the [threshold for answering protected questions](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/new-user) together with 100 points you were given as the association bonus.)

Comment: I wasn't sure whether I should answer this or not. More-or-less it seems as a duplicate of the older question linked above. If the MO community thinks that this answer doesn't add anything to what quid already said in the older thread, I can simply delete my answer. (But even then, I think it is preferable to keep the question rather than delete it. Having several questions about the same thing helps search - the next time somebody wants to ask about this, they might find either this or the older one, depending on the search terms they choose.)